# How can I hide an event created with Graph API from timeline

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating many events for a page using the graph api, up to a couple hundred at a time. However, each event creates a post on the timeline which I'd rather not have happen.

Is there a way when creating the event to have it not show on the timeline? If not, how can I get a reference to the ID for the post on the timeline? I am recording the id of each event as its added if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I've tried setting the 'no_feed_story' parameter to 1 but it doesn't seem to do the trick (in sandbox mode at least).

What I ended up doing is making another query to fetch the page feeds to find the id of the post mentioning the event creation and then deleting it (the publish_stream permission is required for that)

Here is an example in php (sorry I don't work with asp.net):

```
// .. curl was configured and the event created just before this.
$newEventId = $result['id'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/$page/feed?access_token=$accessToken");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

$received_content = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($received_content, true);

foreach ($result['data'] as $feed)
{
  if ($feed['link'] == "https://www.facebook.com/events/$newEventId/")
  {
    $postId = $feed['id'];
    break;
  }
}

if (isset($postId))
{
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/$postId?access_token=$accessToken");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');

  $received_content = curl_exec($ch);

  $result = json_decode($received_content, true);

  var_dump($result);
}
```